# insert a file into postgres

Tags: java, php, sql, spring, postgresql

How do I insert a file that resides in windows in c:\temp\sample.txt

I have tried

```
insert into lob_file VALUES (5, pg_read_file('c://temp//sample.txt')::BYTEA);
```

and got

> ERROR: could not start file c://temp//sample.txt. No such file or
>   directory.

Comment: Try double backslash or single forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Is data base running locally or on a Windows server and you have moved the file to the server. See [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html)

> The functions shown in Table 9.94 provide native access to files on
>   the machine hosting the server. Only files within the database cluster
>   directory and the log_directory can be accessed unless the user is
>   granted the role pg_read_server_files. Use a relative path for files
>   in the cluster directory, and a path matching the log_directory
>   configuration setting for log files.